# Firefox packaging to include addons for network installation

Tags: installation, deployment, package-management, firefox

While looking up information on FireFox here I came across the post: [**Non-IE browsers wont auto-authenticate**](https://serverfault.com/questions/36176/non-ie-browsers-wont-auto-authenticate). which showed how to handle the issue of integrated login for FireFox which also briefly explained how to edit the package to handle setting options in the About.config through the all.js file.

Taking that a step further how would I go about packaging up Adblock Plus to be included in the installation?

Also are there any other plugins that any of you would recommend that will make the browser safer for regular users. I know flashblock would be one but I know anyone that isn't a power user will find it very inconvenient or want it disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Installing extentions](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Installing_extensions#Global_installation) covers the steps needed for installing extensions globally. I install Firefox with [WPKG](http://wpkg.org/) which someone's already [documented how to install extensions](http://wpkg.org/Firefox).